# navigator.share() is unavailable in Quasar Vue 3 PWA

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to use `navigator.share` to share some text content in my `.vue` 3 component file.

```js
navigator.share({ text: 'foo' })
```

but `navigator.share` is `undefined` and logging `navigator does indeed show that` navigator.share` is missing.

[image: navigator.share missing when console.logging it in Quasar PRQ]

I am using Quasar `2.11.9` on Google Chrome V120.0.6099.119 on iOS.

### Questions

- Why is `navigator.share` not available in my Quasar PWA? How can I make it available?
- If there is no way to make it available, what are the alternatives for sharing?

### Tried

```js
console.log(navigator.share) // undefined
```

### Expected

`navigator.share` to be defined.

Comment: What browser (and browser version) are you using and is it [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#browser_compatibility)? The `share` function by the way, is actually found on the Prototype object when logging just `navigator` which you'll have to expand (very bottom of the log).

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response @yoduh!
Updated the issue with the Chrome version (120.0.6099.119 - on iOS).
--
 Also, `share` is not in the prototype when logging from the console of the PWA

Comment: If you check the browser compatibility section of the page I linked, it has a note that Navigator.share is only supported on Chrome for certain operating systems: ChromeOS and Windows.  I think that's your problem since you're using Chrome with iOS.  You could use Safari instead